# Be the infinite extension $ L / F / K $ if $ L / F $ and $ F / K $ are separable, then $ L / K $ separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

For the case where $ L / K $ is a finite extension and F an intermediate field I can show that if $ L / F $ and $ F / K $ are separable then $ L / K $ is separable.

Now assuming $ L / K $ an infinite extension and $ F $ an intermediate field, if $ L / F $ and $ F / K $ are separable, $ L / K $ will be separable? Is it possible to display some examples that are not worth?

Comment: The proof is the same  : take $b \in L$, look at $E = K(a_0,\ldots,a_d)$ the field generated by the coefficients of its $F$-minimal polynomial, then $E(b)/E/K$ is a tower of finite separable extensions, thus the $K$-minimal polynomial of $b$ is separable.

Comment: @reuns I did not do it that way. I use this result: $ E / T $ is separable if, and only if $ [E: T] = [E: T] _s $

Comment: To prove $E(b)/E/K$ is a tower of finite separable extensions implies the $K$-minimal polynomial of $b$ is separable.

Answer (score 2):

$x\in L\Rightarrow$ the minimal polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0$ of $x$ over $F$ is separable $\Rightarrow K[a_0,...,a_{n-1},x]/K[a_0,...,a_{n-1}]$ and $K[a_0,...,a_{n-1}]/K$ separable.

First arrow: $L/F$ is separable

Second arrow: $K[x_1,...,x_n]/K$ separable $\Leftrightarrow x_1,...,x_n$ separable over $K$